# Ruby, iterating through strings, matching exact patterns and replacing each but the first one

Tags: ruby, regex, iteration, pattern-matching

I have a column of strings (cities) in a csv file. I'd need to go through the list, iterate through all matching patterns, keep only the first one and replace all similar ones with blank lines.
I am no programmer, but if I could do this that would help me a lot at work!
I have notions of Ruby and notions of regexp in Emacs.
Is this feasible? Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance!

**File looks like this**:

Bordeaux

Bordeaux

Paris

Paris

Paris

Riom

**File should look like this:**

Bordeaux

(blank)

Paris

(blank)

(blank)

Riom

Comment: Will the names always be grouped together, or could there be others intermingled?

Comment: Also, you say you need to do this with multiple columns from a CSV file? Can you show a more complete example of the input if you're dealing with multiple columns?

Answer (score 2):

Keeping the empty lines:

```
file_in = File.open('test_villes_ruby.txt','r')
file_out = File.open('test_villes_ruby_stripped.txt','w')

memo = ""
file_in.each do |city|
  if city == memo then
    file_out << "\n"
  else
    file_out << city
    memo = city
  end
end

file_in.close
file_out.close
```

Comment: Oh my... Will rewrite, addding output file.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd be thrilled to go through my files in a jiffy... (1,500 lines, about 10 columns in different files). Won't feel so much like a lonesome slave anymore!

Comment: Edited (actually complete rewrite).

Comment: I can't tell you how happy I am with this! It works perfectly well! You have no clue (oh, well, you do) about how much time I am going to save with this! Really, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Sorry, if you had a few seconds to explain how come "city" and "memo" are interpreted as... what? head of a column, that would be very helpful to me when I peruse (ain't gonna become a programmer in a couple of weeks) through Ruby literature...

Comment: memo is initially an empty string. file_in.each takes one line at a time from the file. For the rest of the block (the stuff between do and end) this line will be called 'city'. It could have been 'line' or whatever. "\n" is a linebreak. 'memo' stores the last city that was written to file. Long time ago I started scripting just to save myself from this kind of boring stuff. It's easier than it looks. Start with File, String and Array and see if you can understand blocks. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again. Have a very nice weekend!

Answer (score 1):

For such simple tasks, you can also pass your ruby script directly to the interpreter using `-e` command line parameter. If you combine it with `-n` or `-p`, your ruby script will be performed on every line of the input, in turns. Variable `$_` then holds the content of the line currently being processed.

So, if your input file looks like this:

```
jablan-mbp:dev $ cat test1.txt 
foo
foo
foo
bar
bar
foo
bar
bar
bar
bar
foo
```

You can execute a simple script this way:

```
jablan-mbp:dev $ ruby -n -e 'puts(@memo == $_ ? "" : @memo = $_)' < test1.txt 
foo


bar

foo
bar



foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
File.open('cities', 'r') do |f_in|
  File.open('cities_uniq', 'w') do |f_out|
    f_in.inject("") { |o, c| f_out.puts o == c ? "\n" : c ; c}
  end
end
```

Input:

```
Bordeaux
Bordeaux
Paris
Paris
Paris
Riom
Riom
Riom
Frankfurt
Wien
Wien
```

Output:

```
Bordeaux

Paris


Riom


Frankfurt
Wien
```

Note: There's an empty line after the final "Wien", but I can't get it to display here...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simpliest way is just to use a set (or SortedSet if order matters)

```
cities = Set.new

cities_in_csv.each do |city|
  cities.add(city)
end
```

Nothing extra. Sets by definition do not contain duplicate elements.

Comment: OP asked for duplicated elements to be replaced by newlines.

Comment: Thanks for that. I missed that part. It's what I get for answering a question late at night.